Question about when two quotient spaces are the same
We can define $\mathbb{RP}^2$ as $\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus\{0\}$ with lines identified, or $S^2$ with antipodal points identified, or the closed 2-disk with antipodal points on the boundary identified. This is fine because we still have at least one representative of each equivalence class. However, if we take out too many points, like say if we take out half the points from the boundary of the disk, we get a space with the wrong topology. So my question is, when trying to simplify a quotient space by taking out some points, is there any rule for which points we can take out without disturbing the topology?

Here's a somewhat boring condition that you can get just by following the definitions.
By definition, a continuous surjective map $f : X \to Y$ is a quotient map if and only if $f$ induces a bijection between the set of saturated open sets of $X$ and the set of open sets of $Y$.
Now suppose you wish to replace $X$ with a subspace $A \subset X$ and you still want the restriction $f \mid A : A \to Y$ be a quotient map. Of course $f \mid A$ must still be surjective. And the other condition is that $f \mid A$ must induce a bijection between saturated open subsets of $A$ --- with respect to the subspace topology --- and open subsets of $A$. This is equivalent to the statement that the saturated open subsets of $A$ are precisely the intersections with $A$ of the saturated open subsets of $X$.
The trouble is that if $A$ is not carefully chosen then it may have a new saturated open set that is not the intersection with $A$ of any saturated open subset of $X$.
So consider your example where you start with the usual quotient map $f : \mathbb D^2 \to \mathbb R P^2$ and then you remove an half-open semicircle to form the subset $A \subset \mathbb D^2$. If you take one of the nonremoved boundary points of $A$, that point has a saturated open neighborhood which is not the intersection with $A$ of some saturated open subset of $\mathbb D^2$.
